# Evaluation of the integral. (Using Polar coodinates.)

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Can anyone prove this equality?
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)\int_{|y|<1}\frac{e^{ix\cdot y}\ -1}{|y|^2}dydx=\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{r}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{i|x|r\cos\theta}\ -1)d\theta dr dx,$$ where $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb C$ is in Schwartz class.

This equality is in my text book and this says that this can be shown by changing variables : $y_1=r\cos\theta, y_2=r\sin\theta.$

Using the method, I have
\begin{align}
LHS
&=\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i(x_1\  r\cos\theta+x_2 \ r\sin\theta)}\quad \ -1}{r^2}rd\theta drdx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)\int_0^1\frac{1}{r}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{i(x_1\  r\cos\theta+x_2 \ r\sin\theta)}\quad \ -1) d\theta dr dx.
\end{align}

Is this equal to $\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{r}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{i|x|r\cos\theta}\ -1)d\theta dr dx$ ?

I cannot see.

(The textbook is written in Japanese so most of you cannot read it.)

Comment: You rotate your axis for $y$ so that the first coordinate align with the direction of $x$ (cutting out the $x=0$ case doesn't change the integral).  Then use the substitution $y_1=r\cos\theta$, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more ? You say that for each $x$, I should evaluate the integral with regard to $y$ by rotate $y$ axis  ? How ? @user10354138

Comment: If you don't like that description, I'll use another: instead of measuring the polar angle $\theta$ as angle between $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{e_1}$-axis on the $x$-plane (pushed to the $y$-plane via some isometry of the two) you measure it between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.  That is, if $x=(x^1,x^2)$, then $y^1$ measures the projection of $\vec{y}$ onto that line and $y^2$ measures the orthogonal direction $(-x^2,x^1)$.

Comment: So that when you convert $(y^1,y^2)$ into polars, you will recover exactly $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=\lvert x\rvert r\cos\theta$, $\mathrm{d}^2\vec{y}=\mathrm{d}y^1\,\mathrm{d}y^2=r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ etc.